# Can I have two ng-repeat values, where one applies when boolean is true?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an element that is repeated.

```
<li ng-repeat="plan in displayedPlans"> ... </li>
```

I'd like to add limitTo to it to show the first two plans.

```
<li ng-repeat="plan in displayedPlans|limitTo:2"> ... </li>
```

But now I want limitTo to only apply if a boolean (called "experiment" in this example) is true. One of the ways I tried to accomplish my goal is something like this (which didn't work) -

```
 <li ng-repeat="plan in displayedPlans, plan in displayedPlans|limitTo:2 : experiment"> ... </li>
```

I also tried putting the ng-repeat value in curly braces and separating the two options with || but that didn't work. I'm wondering if there is a clean solution I can use in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of `limitTo` depending on experiment. It its true set it to 2, else 10000.

Comment: So I tried that as <li ng-repeat="plan in displayedPlans | limitTo: 2 ? experiment : 3"> but that resulted in nothing shown. Probably has to do with my syntax. I'm still quite new to Javascript and Angular.

Comment: Try this `<li ng-repeat="plan in displayedPlans | limitTo: experiment ? 2 : 3">`. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PB5P2dhDD836mkssVlOo?p=preview). You should start learning the basics if you wanna use them ;-). Ternary operators work in most languages all the same. Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).